# How to simulate field of view in orthographic mode?

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, orthographic, fieldofview

As the title goes, how do I simulate the field of view if I'm using orthographic projection in Unity3D?
My guess is to make the speed of different layers different. So for example, the background layer will move much slower than the front layer so that it feels like there's some kind of pseudo-field-of-view happening. But I don't know the code for it. And I don't know how much slower should the background move in comparison to the layers in front of it.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you tell us why you are doing this? I just don’t understand why you want to put field of view on orthographic. I don’t think that is possible. If you tell us your project, we may find a better way of solving this.

Comment: Yes, to put it simply, I'm doing a mockup of Ori: the blind forest.

Comment: So, it’s a 2d game. I haven’t played it, but I have looked up pictures of the game. I think they just created the sprites so it looked like it had fov. There is no current way of doing fov with an orthographic camera. I am not 100% sure how fov works, but you could try a perspective camera with either a really high or low fov (I’m not sure which one does it, if any) to try and get closer to the orthographic one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably trying to setup a parallax camera effect. There are a bunch of solutions, [one](https://answers.unity.com/questions/551808/parallax-scrolling-using-orthographic-camera.html), [another](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mp6BWCMJZH4), [one more](https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/MichalBerlinger/20160323/268657/Combining_Perspective_and_Orthographic_Camera_for_Parallax_Effect_in_2D_Game.php).